# React delete from SQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a little desktop application that communicates with a SQL database. When i open the application I get a list of all the students who are registered in the database. When I click on a specific student I get more information about them, and I can edit their info. I also tried adding a delete button but this is where  I need help. The code looks like this:

```js
class Students1Details extends Component {
  student1 = null
  program = []

  render() {
    if (!this.student1) return null
    return (
      <ul>
        <li>Name: <input 
            value={this.student1.name}
            onChange={(event) => {
              this.student1.name = event.currentTarget.value;}}></input>
            </li>

        <li>Email: <input value={this.student1.email}
        onChange={(event) => {
          this.student1.email = event.currentTarget.value}}></input>
        </li>
        <li>Program:  <input value={this.program}
        onChange={(event) => {
          this.program = event.currentTarget.value
        }}></input></li>
      <button onClick={() => {
        studentService.updateStudent(this.student1, () => {
          Students1Details.instance().mounted()
        })
      }} >Update</button>

      <button id="hei" onClick={() => {
        studentService.deleteStudent(this.student1, () => {})
      }}>Delete</button>

      </ul>
    )
  }
  mounted() {
    studentService.getStudent(this.props.match.params.id, (student1) => {
      this.student1 = student1

      studyProgramService.getStudyProgram(this.student1.studyProgramId, (program) => 
      (this.program = program.name))
     
      studentService.deleteStudent(this.props.match.params.id, (student1) => {
        this.student1 = student1 
      })

      
    })
  }
  
}
```

the deleteStudent function looks like this:

```
deleteStudent(id, success) {
pool.query("DELETE FROM Students WHERE id = ?", [id], (error, results) => {
  if (error) console.error(error)
  success(results)
})
```

}

The problem I have is that as soon as I click on the student name, it gets deleted from the database, instead of being sent to the page where I see the information of the student, and is able to either edit or delete him/her.

Comment: You call `studentService.deleteStudent()` in your `mounted()` method. Probably shouldn't do that there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calling deleteStudent in mounted(). This is probably your issue.

Comment: So how would I call it only when the button is clicked?

Comment: It appears that you already have this wired in the onClick handler for the Save button.  I think you need a new Delete button that fires the current event handler instead of doing it on Save.

Comment: Yeah my assumption was that it only would run when I clicked the button, since thats where its wired to. But it seems like it runs as soon I click the name. Sorry I just  started learning React so im not entirely sure how i need to change the code for it to only run OnClick and not as soon as I click the name

Comment: If you remove the deleteStudent call from mounted() and check your buttons.... This one { <button id="hei" onClick={() => {
        studentService.deleteStudent(this.student1, () => {})
      }}>Save</button>} will call the delete even though the button says Save

Comment: I fixed it! :) (the button was supposed to say Delete but was a typo). I removed it from mounted and made a new function outside called delete: delete() {
    studentService.deleteStudent(this.props.match.params.id, (student1) => {
      this.student1 = student1 
    })
  } and on the button i did this:  <button id="hei" onClick={this.delete}>Delete</button>